# Compact Kaehler submanifolds of projectivized Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, complex-geometry

If we take a separable complex Hilbert space $H$, its projective space $PH$ is an infinite-dimensional Kähler manifold in a fairly obvious sense (see below).   Suppose $M \subset PH$ is a finite-dimensional compact Kähler submanifold of $PH$. Must there be a finite-dimensional linear subspace $V \subset H$ such that $M \subset PV$?

(I don't know a good reference for infinite-dimensional Kähler manifolds but the relevant concept here seems clear.  $PH$ is a smooth [Hilbert manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold) that can be covered with charts modeled on a *complex* Hilbert space, with transition functions that are holomorphic (given in a neighborhood of each point by an absolutely convergent power series).  This makes each tangent space of $PH$ into a complex vector space, and this complex vector space structure extends to a complex Hilbert space structure, which varies smoothly---in fact real-analytically---from point to point.  The imaginary part of the inner product gives $PH$ a symplectic structure, and the real part gives $PH$ a Riemannian structure, both of which are strongly nondegenerate: i.e. they each give an isomorphism  $T_p PH \to T^*_p PH$ of the underlying real Hilbert spaces.)

Comment: Is this somehow related to the concept of geometric quantization? To be more specific, does this have to do with the fact that to any compact Kähler manifold one can associate a finite dimensional quantum Hilbert space reflecting the size of the classical phase space ?

Comment: Yes; I'd like this to be true for some work I'm doing on geometric quantization.

Comment: I think you can argue like this: $PH$ has a hyperplane bundle, which pulls back to a line bundle $L$ on $M$. The inclusion $M\subset PH$ can be written in homogeneous coordinates as $z\mapsto [s_0(z):s_1(z):...]$ where the $s_j$'s are global holomorphic sections of $L$. If the image of $M$ is not contained in any finite-dimensional linear subspace then the sections $s_j$'s would be linearly independent (and there are countably many of them). But the dimension of the space of global sections $H^0(M,L)$ is finite since $M$ is compact, contradiction.

Comment: That's what I've been thinking - especially _after_ I posted my question.  This argument seems sort of magical to me because it leverages some finiteness of the intrinsic geometry of $M$ (the finite-dimensionality of $H^0(M,L)$ to get finiteness of its extrinsic geometry (the finite-dimensional of the smallest projective space in which $M$ sits.)

Comment: Note: That argument is in Remark 2.2.9 of Loi-Zedda ([2018](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3838438); [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04298)). But I’m not (yet quite) convinced it can be turned into a watertight proof of the present conjecture — which they don’t claim.

Comment: What are the possible problems?